# Build docker image using mvn and jib through a proxy

Tags: docker, maven, aws-codebuild, maven-jib

I'm running this command to build `docker` image using `maven` and `jib`
`mvn compile jib:dockerBuild -Djib.to.image="$IMAGE_NAME"`
this command works perfectly fine on my machine since it's going to download some stuff from the internet, however, it's not the case when I try to run it within a pipeline (on AWS) that is going to run in a corporate network that requires a proxy
I have already tried this command:
`export MAVEN_OPTS="-DsocksProxyHost=<host> -DsocksProxyPort=<port>"`
but it didn't work, and I don't want to touch the `settings.xml` file because I don't have access to it, so the only solution I'm loking for is to provide a proxy with the command listed above.
this is the whole log of the command:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/kr/motd/maven/os-maven-plugin/1.6.2/os-maven-plugin-1.6.2.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin kr.motd.maven:os-maven-plugin:1.6.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for kr.motd.maven:os-maven-plugin:jar:1.6.2 @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.bla:backend:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/codebuild/output/src794035415/src/backend/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin kr.motd.maven:os-maven-plugin:1.6.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for kr.motd.maven:os-maven-plugin:jar:1.6.2: Could not transfer artifact kr.motd.maven:os-maven-plugin:pom:1.6.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/kr/motd/maven/os-maven-plugin/1.6.2/os-maven-plugin-1.6.2.pom: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException

[Container] 2021/02/26 11:15:48 Command did not exit successfully cd backend && mvn compile jib:dockerBuild -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://path/to/proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Djib.to.image="$JAVA_SERVICE_IMAGE_NAME" && cd .. exit status 1
[Container] 2021/02/26 11:15:48 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED_WITH_ABORT
[Container] 2021/02/26 11:15:48 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cd backend && mvn compile jib:dockerBuild -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://path/to/proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Djib.to.image="$JAVA_SERVICE_IMAGE_NAME" && cd ... Reason: exit status 1
```

Comment: Is this entry in the faq helpful? https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-configure-a-proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways. First, check out this [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) to understand what are the standard Java networking properties you can set.

1. Set proxy configuration in `settings.xml` (the Maven settings file). For example,

   ```xml
     <proxies>
       <proxy>
         <id>for-https-proxying</id> <!-- Make sure you use different IDs -->
         <!-- For HTTPS proxying. AFAIK, the Maven doc is wrong about this. -->
         <protocol>https</protocol>
         <host>my.company.proxy.com</host>
         <nonProxyHosts>localhost|srv-abc|*.int</nonProxyHosts>
       </proxy>
       <proxy>
         <id>for-http-proxying</id>
         <protocol>http</protocol>  <!-- for HTTP proxying  -->
         <host>my.company.proxy.com</host>
         <nonProxyHosts>localhost|srv-abc|*.int</nonProxyHosts>
       </proxy>
     </proxies>
   ```

   Check out the [Maven Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more details.
2. Set the networking system properties when running Jib (JVM). For example, one the command-line,

   ```
   $ mvn -Dhttp.proxyHost=my.company.proxy.com \
         -Dhttp.proxyPort=... \
         -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=... \
         -Dhttps.proxyHost=... \
         -Dhttps.proxyPort=... \
         compile jib:build
   ```

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/1403